# Can WPF listview be used to capture user input?

Tags: wpf, listview, controls, user-input

I want my users to capture some data in a "grid" or "table"-like interface...

I want the users to register event_description, event_stationing and event_comments. User can enter 1 to n events at a time, thus the table-like interface.

I am building my application with VB .NET and WPF (and very obviously learning WPF).

May I use WPF listview to accomplish this? How? (I have successfully used it to display data, but taking user input is not obvious to me).

Comment: `ListView` is more for viewing data, a `DataGrid` might be a better choice..

Comment: Agreed... but somehow ListView seems "cleaner" to use to me super WPF newbie... DataGrid seems more confusing.

Comment: Well, it is more complex but hence also more flexible

Answer (score 1):

We do this in our applications. It's very handy. Like editing a grid only without the hassle of using a freaking Grid. Nice, lightweight and you OWN the layout. Check this out:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="MyData" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <sys:String>Red</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Green</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This works just fine, WPF orders all the controls and their tab stops for you - and the user experience is brilliant. Using checkboxes with this approach is espcially nice.

Note: in my sample, Array does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. But I wanted to keep it simple so you can see the point.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much ! Will give it a try and come back to vote!